# Gatsby Rewrite Slug with gatsby-node.js does not change the url

Tags: gatsby

I'm following the [official documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/programmatically-creating-pages/#generate-slugs) to have a custom slug using the gatsby-node.js but once the system is running, it is like if I had no custom configuration at all.

I can confirm using the GraphQL or visiting the website: both show the slugs from the folders structure and not the one I programmatically changed.

What I am trying to achieve is to remove the year folder in the URL. When I am setting a breakpoint in the `gatsby-node.js` I see that the value for the createNodeField is set to my modified `newSlug`. I have deleted the cache folder and re-run: no change. Here is the code that I am sure it is executed.

```
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;
  if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
    const relativeFilePath = createFilePath({
      node,
      getNode,
      trailingSlash: false,
    });
    const newSlug = relativeFilePath.substring(6); // Remove the year
    const url = `/blog/${newSlug}`;
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value: url,
    });
  }
};
```

I expect to have `/blog/my-article` but it is still to `/blog/2021/my-article`, any idea?

Comment: Can you share the `createPages` information? I think you are creating properly the node but don't applying it

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it seems that you are creating properly the node (as for the debug information you've provided). My guess, is that besides you are creating the new slug correctly, you might be not applying it in the page creation (`createPages`).

Your new slug field is created under `field` node (resulting in `node.fields.slug`), so your final query should look like this:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query')
  }

  const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

  posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/components/posts-page-layout.js`),
      context: { id: node.id },
    })
  })
}
```

The `path` property is where you set the path for the dynamically created page so, that should result in `/blog/${newSlug}`.

Comment: Thank you @Ferran. You are right, the default code uses a different slug than the one I am creating. Thus, there is the default `slug` under the `node` field and the new one under the `node>fields`. I also revisited the documentation and the section under the one I took the former code has the code you suggested. Now, it works. Thank you for your time. I appreciate.

Comment: I'm glad we finally figured it out. If the issue has been solved, please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the topic